Why is my simple vec3 pyo3 pyclass so much slower than py glm's equivalent class at construction and multiplication?
I'm trying to create a Python extension in Pyo3 that creates a type that is similar to a vec3/glm vec3, but instead from rust.
I've created the following directory structure:
.
├── Cargo.toml
├── pyproject.toml
├── python
│  └── main.py
└── src
   └── lib.rs

Where only lib.rs and main.py are custom made, the rest was generated by maturin init
lib.rs is :
use pyo3::prelude::*;

#[pyclass]
#[derive(Clone)]
struct Float3{
    #[pyo3(get, set)]
    x : f64,
    #[pyo3(get, set)]
    y : f64,
    #[pyo3(get, set)]
    z : f64,
}
#[pymethods]
impl Float3 {
    #[new]
    fn py_new(x : f64, y : f64, z : f64) -> Self {
        Float3 { x, y, z}
    }
    
    fn __rmul__ (&self, lhs : f64) -> Self{
        return Float3{ x: self.x * lhs, y : self.y * lhs, z : self.z * lhs};
    }

    fn __mul__ (&self, lhs : f64) -> Self{
        return Float3{ x: self.x * lhs, y : self.y * lhs, z : self.z * lhs};
    }

    fn __add__ (&self, lhs : &Self) -> Self{
        return Float3{x : self.x + lhs.x,  y: self.y + lhs.y, z: self.z + lhs.z};
    }
    
    fn __sub__ (&self, lhs : &Self) -> Self{
        return Float3{x : self.x - lhs.x,  y: self.y - lhs.y, z: self.z - lhs.z};
    }


    fn __iadd__ (&mut self, lhs : &Self) -> (){
        *self = Float3{x : self.x + lhs.x,  y: self.y + lhs.y, z: self.z + lhs.z}; 
    }
    
    fn __isub__ (&mut self, lhs : &Self) -> (){
        *self = Float3{x : self.x - lhs.x,  y: self.y - lhs.y, z: self.z - lhs.z};
    }
}


/// A Python module implemented in Rust.
#[pymodule]
fn test_pyo3(_py: Python, m: &PyModule) -> PyResult<()> {
    m.add_class::<Float3>()?; 
    Ok(())
}

And main.py is:
import test_pyo3
import glm 
import time

def main():

    samples = 100000
    tic = time.time()
    for i in range(samples):
        temp = glm.dvec3(0.0, 0.0, 9.81)
    print("average time per construction glm {}".format((time.time() - tic) / samples))    
    tic = time.time()
    for i in range(samples):
        temp = test_pyo3.Float3(0.0, 0.0, 9.81)
    print("average time per construction test_pyo3 {}".format((time.time() - tic) / samples))    
    tic = time.time()
    for i in range(samples):
        temp = 1.5 * glm.dvec3(0.0, 0.0, 9.81)
    print("average time per multiply operation glm {}".format((time.time() - tic) / samples))    
    tic = time.time()
    for i in range(samples):
        temp = 1.5 *  test_pyo3.Float3(0.0, 0.0, 9.81)
    print("average time per multiply operation test_pyo3 {}".format((time.time() - tic) / samples))    
    pass




if __name__ == '__main__':
    main()

main.py runs a benchmark on constructing glm.dvec3, multiplying with a scalar, and the equivalent for my class.
The output is :
average time per construction glm 2.125263214111328e-07
average time per construction test_pyo3 2.834796905517578e-07
average time per construction glm 2.486872673034668e-07
average time per construction test_pyo3 4.966330528259277e-07

I compile the rust side with "maturin develop -r" which should build in release, and I set pyo3 to be pyo3 = "0.21.2"  in my Cargo.toml
There's a 40 ish percentage between construction, and nearly 2x performance reduction in simple scalar multiplication. When looking at the call graph using py-spy, all I see is "trampoline" everywhere with a  bunch of random numbers, and it's not clear what is actually going on.  Regardless, this should be an apples to apples comparison, PyGLM is just using C bindings directly, and not using rust to do so.  I wouldn't expect there to be a massive difference in performance with such a simple test case, both should be doing the same kind of work.
Is there a way to bring the performance of my simple class more inline with PyGLM?

In addition to what I said in my answer, I'm not sure your benchmark is representative.

@ChayimFriedman What do  you mean by representative?  Do you just mean that the overhead is not as big of a factor in other scenarios?  This slow down in this example actually does manifest itself in massive slowdowns in the real codebase this is based off of in that case, and we are directly comparing against PyGLM in that scenario as well.

I mean that it may not be accurate, do to the overhead being dwarfed by the loop. But I may be wrong.

@ChayimFriedman We are using the same loop in both PyGLM and PyO3, are you just saying that it adds some time?  If anything, removing that static overhead  would mean the performance differences would be more apparent not less right?

It is well known that PyO3 micro-performance is not the same as using bare CPython API. All the goodies that PyO3 automatically adds have their overhead, and even ignoring that, there is a bunch of optimization work that can be done in PyO3 and wasn't done yet. See https://github.com/PyO3/pyo3/issues?q=is%3Aissue+is%3Aopen+performance.
In general, I don't recommend PyO3 for micro-optimization, at least currently. If you have a bunch of work you can do in native code, great; if not, this will probably be a lot of effort for almost nothing.

Is there a way to still leverage the FFI stuff here?  It's not clear how to even use that from PyO3's documentation AFAICT.  We'd prefer not to throw the baby out with the bath water here, but these are representative of real world performance losses of approximately the same ratio, just greater in magnitude, we operate on thousands of elements, so the performance difference ends up being pretty massive.

@Krupip If you can do more in Rust land, this will be a great solution.
